# why innerText not working on firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the value of pop up after I clicked it. It is giving value on Chrome, but it will not work on Firefox, why?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLNSw/) is my fiddle.

These are the following steps I did:

1. Click on test button (open pop up).
2. Select any value of pop up show on alert.

On Chrome it shows, but on Firefox it gives "undefined".

```
$(function () {
  $('#test').click(function () {
      $("#commadsPopup").popup("open");
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.commandRow a', function() {
    var str = this.innerText;
    alert(str);
});
```

Comment: The duplicate is the plain JS solution, but if you're using jQuery, just use [`$(this).text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) -- solving cross-browser headaches is exactly what jQuery is for.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)** instead:

```
var str = this.textContent;
```

or apply jQuery using **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
var str=  $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerText` is not supported by Firefox! Internet Explorer introduced element.innerText.
Use `textContent` instead

[MDN: textContent - Differences from innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText)